# How should one properly handle opening and closing of Azure Service Bus/Topic Clients in an Azure Function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm not sure of the proper way to manage the lifespans of the various clients necessary to interact with the Azure Service Bus. From my understanding there are three different but similar clients to manage: ServiceBusClient, a Topic/Queue/Subscription Service, and then a Sender of some sort. In my case, its TopicService and a Sender. Should I close the sender after every message? After a certain amount of downtime? And same with all the others? I feel like I should keep the ServiceBusClient open until the function is entirely complete, so that probably carries over to the Topic Client as well. There's just so many ways to skin this one, I'm not sure where to start to draw the line. I'm pretty sure it's not this extreme:

```
function sendMessage(message: SendableMessageInfo) {
    let client=createServiceBusClientFromConnectionString(connectionString)
    let tClient = createTopicClient(client);
    const sender = tClient.createSender();
    sender.send(message);
    sender.close();
    tClient.close();
    client.close();
}
```

But leaving everything open all the time seems like a memory leak waiting to happen. Should I handle this all through error handling? Try-catch, then close everything in a finally block?

I could also just use the Azure Function binding, correct me if I'm wrong:

```
const productChanges: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, products: product[]): Promise<void> {
    context.bindings.product_changes = []
    for (let product of product) {
        if(product.updated) {
            let message = this.createMessage(product)
            context.bindings.product_changes.push(message)
        }
    }
    context.done();
}
```

I can't work out from the docs or source which would be better (both in terms of performance and finances) for an extremely high throughput Topic (at surge, ~100,000 requests/sec).

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, we'd better use Azure binding or set the client static but not create the client every time. If use Azure binding, we will not consider the problem about close the sender, if set the client static, it's ok too. Both of the solutions have good performance and there is no difference in cost (you can refer to this tutorial for servicebus price: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/service-bus/) between these twos. Hope it would be helpful to your question.

Comment: could you expand on "set the client static" with respect to azure functions?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply, but I'll try to explain the concepts behind the clients below in case someone lands here looking for answers.

#### Version 1

```
_ ServiceBusClient (maintains the connection)
  |_ TopicClient
     |_ Sender (sender link)
```

#### Version 7

```
_ ServiceBusClient (maintains the connection)
  |_ ServiceBusSender (sender link)
```

In both version 1 and version 7 of `@azure/service-bus` SDK, when you use the `sendMessages` method or the equivalent `send` method for the first time, a connection is created on the `ServiceBusClient` if there was none and the new sender link is created.

The sender link remains active for a while and is cleared on its own(by the SDK) if there is no activity. Even if it is closed by inactivity, the subsequent send call even after waiting for a long duration would work just fine since it creates a new sender link.

Once you're done using the `ServiceBusClient`, you can close the client and all the internal senders, receivers are also closed with this if they are not already closed individually.

The latest version 7.0.0 of `@azure/service-bus` has been released recently.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)